# Unit testing function in a class that injects EntityManager

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs, entitymanager, typeorm

I need help adding unit test to the function below in NestJs.
I have a class with a createOrder function as shown below. the constructor of the class injects an Entity Manager. How can I test for the createOrder function in jest.

```js
    import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
    import * as shortId from 'shortid';
    import { EntityManager, Repository } from 'typeorm';
    import { HttpException, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';

    import { Service } from 'models/service.model';
    
    @Injectable()
    export class OrderService {
      private readonly orderRepository: Repository<Service>;
    
      constructor(private readonly entityManager: EntityManager) {
        this.orderRepository = entityManager.getRepository(Service);
      }
    
      async createOrder(data) {
        const orderService = new Service();

        orderService.id = shortId.generate(); // just to generate a string for id
    
        const orderServiceData = Object.assign(orderService, data);
    
        try {
          
          await this.orderRepository.save(orderServiceData);
          
          return { success: true };
        } catch (err) {
          throw new HttpException('Post not found', HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
      }
    }
```

This is what I have tried so far. Yet it fails to call the save function

```js
    import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
    import { OrderService } from './order_service.service';
    import { Service } from '../../models/service.model';
    import { Repository, EntityManager, getRepository } from 'typeorm';
    import { getRepositoryToken } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
    
    describe('Order Service', () => {
      let orderService: OrderServiceService;
      let orderRepository: Repository<Service>;
    
      const mockOrderRepository = () => ({
        save: jest.fn(),
      });
    
      const mockEntityManager = () => ({
        getRepository: jest.fn(),
      });
    
      beforeEach(async () => {
        const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
          providers: [
            OrderService,
            {
              provide: EntityManager,
              useFactory: mockEntityManager,
            },
            {
              provide: getRepositoryToken(Service),
              useFactory: mockOrderRepository,
            },
          ],
        }).compile();
    
        orderService = await module.get<OrderService>(
          OrderService,
        );
        orderRepository = await module.get(getRepositoryToken(Service));
      });
    
      it('should check that order service is defined', () => {
        expect(orderService).toBeDefined();
      });
    
      describe('Create order service', () => {
        it('should create an order service', () => {
          expect(orderRepository.save).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
          const data = {
            name: 'Gucci Cloths',
            type: 'Cloths',
          };
    
          orderService.createOrder(data);
          expect(orderRepository.save).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you need to inject the `EntityManager` as opposed to just injecting the `Repository<Service>`? It would be easier to mock the functionality directly against the repo

Comment: @JesseCarter seems to have other benefits as used elsewhere in the class. Though, not related to this function.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is mocking the save function of the `orderRepository`:

```
const mockRepository = {
  save: jest.fn(),
}

const mockEntityManager = () => ({
  getRepository: () => mockRepository,
});
```

This way you can test the function and also check that the `save` function has been called with the right parameters.

Comment: if I do this, it complains that the `entityManager.getRepository is not a function`